# Where is the "Object" menu?

Tags: interface

For some reason, the Object menu...

[image]

... is missing in my project.

How do I show it again?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: on the bottom of your window? you can bring it back to the top with a right click

Comment: I'm not sure of his question actually  ^^

Comment: +1 -> moonboots is the master of finding menu...and the rest of Blender ;)

Comment: moonboots looking for lost menu: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a1YuRH4onms9_Ag2-KkA_0BsiHbz0xOd4w-YgHeknYk3CFCy0nHYkyu4cd1CLvbl3Ljipg4pVIShrEGXT8dM-BiP7hz9qN-CPLfZxQ=w600-l80-sg-rj

Comment: @moonboots Thank you! Right-Click the menu on the bottom and then "Flip to Top".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is on the bottom of your window, you can bring it back to the top with a right click > *Flip to Top*